# How to solve $x = e^{1/(4x)}$?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I need to find the solution to this equation :

$$ x = e^{1/(4x)} $$

Can you give me a hint ?

Comment: Lambert W function or numerical methods.

Comment: Thus $x\log x=1/4$, hence... "Lambert W function or numerical methods." :-)

Comment: Can I resolve it without using Lambert W ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the Newton Method and use the function $y=x\log x-\frac{1}{4}$
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{y_n}{y'_n}$$

then
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+1/4}{1+\log x_n}$$
at $x_0=1$ to get
$$x1=1.25$$
$$x_2=1.226348288$$
$$x_3=1.226161263$$
$$x_4=1.226161251$$
$$x_5=1.226161251$$

Comment: First you have to choose the proper $x_0$, otherwise the sequence won't converge.

Comment: @Santiago Guessing by looking at a graph should suffice to find $x_0$.

Comment: @E.H.E Any $x_0<e^{-1}$ is undefined, best to stick as close to the answer from graphing as you can.

Comment: @E.H.E If $x_0<e^{-1}$, then $x_1<0$, so $x_2$ is undefined.

Comment: Inspection could have been a good idea since $y(1)=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $y(1)=2 \log (2)-\frac{1}{4} \approx 1.13629$. Approximating by the secant would give $x_0=1+\frac{1}{8 \log (2)} \approx 1.18$.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer was given above. We can also write $$x = \frac{1/4}{W(1/4)},$$

where $W$ denotes the Lambert W function defined as an inverse of $f(z) = z \exp z$, e.g. $$z = W (z\exp z) \iff f(z) = z \exp z.$$

Comment: I don't get why you copy pasted the braces from the mathematica output?

Comment: For the sake of self-containedness (you are referring to comments, which are neither linked to in your answer nor meant to be, as comments are not meant to last), can you define what $W$ is in your answer? And, maybe, also explain that it's a non-elementary function, and that there is no simpler expression for that value?

Comment: W denotes the so called Lambert-W function

Comment: I know... but your answer does not say so, and it cannot be assumed to be common knowledge. And searching Google for "W" won't really help much someone that doesn't know it.

Comment: I doubt that our teacher what a Lambert W : Let me explain : I arrived to x = e^(1/(4x)) becouse I need to find where ln(x) -1/(4x) = 0 , in order to find the solutions of  f(x) = ln(x) -1/(4x)

Comment: @NPLS So this is a homework problem?

Comment: nope , a failed exam exercize